# Changing the virtualenv for the terminal in pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

I was postponing this question since i am not sure this is the right place to ask it. But i don't find a clear answer either.

I am running pycharm 2018.1.4, on windows and it seems that i can't change the virtual env that running in the terminal in pycharm. When i check the python version in the terminal i get version 2.7.3, for the project interpreter i have python 3.6 and for my run configurations i have the same 3.6 interpreter. There are no problems running the development server or anything like that, just in the terminal i can't run the manage.py script without getting following.

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and
>   available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to
>   activate a virtual environment?

I understand the error, i just dont get why it is using that virtuals env instead of the one configured as project interpreter. Anyone else stumbled upon this problem?

Comment: Have u tried using the virtual environment from command prompt? Does is still use v2 even there?

Comment: Or, Could you tell me the command you used to create the VirtualEnvironment in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, Pycharm's terminal is not bound to Project Interpreter and the IDE related features.
To make it work, you'll have to manually activate your virtualenv in the terminal.

Comment: It is possible to create a virtualenv inside this terminal and to activate it, it is also possible to do this through pycharm itself and this kind off messed up the project. I ended up looking up both virtual environements, deleting them to make sure only one was available and creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to various reasons, 
You can try the following command once the virtualenv is activated

```
python --version
```

If it shows python 2.7 as the version then it means in your system you have given python command to respond to the 2.7 version. Its more like a name tag.

Try `python3 --version` and it should give you back "Python 3.6".

If that's the case, then use `python3 manage.py runserver` and it should work perfectly

Comment: [here](https://i.imgur.com/4n236ml.png) is a screenshot of the setup, below you can see the terminal failing, python3 is not even working. But i am not really concerned about that. I just want it to be the same interpreter as the one defined as project interpreter.

Comment: Did you try my answer and see any results?

Comment: Yes, python3 was not installed in the virtualenv that was running on the terminal

Comment: So install ur virtualenv using python3, then u can see the python version as 3.

Comment: U can start a virtual env explicitly in python3 using ‘virtualenv -p python3 envname’

Comment: Okay thank you :), but actually as pybuche stated, it is possible that in the terminal there is another virtualenv running in the terminal. I had a two venvs with the same name, one with python 2.7 installed and no django , and one which had all the correct modules. activating the correct virtualenv in the terminal manually fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Pycharm go to project setting,then go to project interpreter make sure that you have your required python virtual environment (which I think you did it already)
2. Under same selected environment, make sure that you have installed Django
3. Of course, if there is the dependency on Django, you can just type

   ```
   pip install django
   ```

Comment: The project interpreter has django installed, i don't think that the virtual environment running here  is running in the terminal. To make things clear, [here](https://i.imgur.com/4n236ml.png) is a screenshot of the setup, below you can see the terminal failing

Comment: ok.then you have 2.7.3 python version available so in that python go to "C:\Python27\Scripts" and just do--> pip install django